# \setcounter{enumi} isn't set when resume within enumitem list

Tags: enumitem

The following MWE shows the situation. Although I set `enumi` back to 1, the `resume` which comes afterwards still maintains it's effect. I know that I can simply remove the `resume` option but I was rather hoping that this would not be needed for the sake of consistency within my document and the idea I have mind.

So there are two related questions: why does this behaviour happen (since to me it is counter intuitive) and how can one achieve the desired result without having to remove resume?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[resume]
    \item hello
    \item hello
    \item hello
\end{enumerate}

\setcounter{enumi}{1}

\begin{enumerate}[resume]
    \item hello
    \item hello
    \item hello
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

EDIT: To clarify my intention, I was hoping to create a macro that I can simply move around when the need arises that would from that point start the counter at 1. The idea is not to need to dig into the lists as they are. This macro would be obviously more complicated than what this MWE, which highlights a part which doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use \restartlist if you want to cancel a resume key:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[resume]
    \item hello
    \item hello
    \item hello
\end{enumerate}


\restartlist{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
    \item hello
    \item hello
    \item hello
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this (the star version `resume*` uses all the layout characteristics of the previous list):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[resume]
    \item hello
    \item hello
    \item hello
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[resume*, start=1]
    \item hello
    \item hello
    \item hello
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I was wanting a solution that didn't need to change the optional values within the `enumitem`. The idea was to make a macro that sort of says: begin new exercises. If the macro is not there then resume kicks in.

Comment: What's the difference between `setcounter{enumi}{1}` and adding the  key `start=1`, except the latter works? You *have* to neutralise the effect of `resume`  on the counter.

Comment: The difference is that I can build something like setcounter as a macro without having to dig into the following enumerate lists. At least that is how I see it. I assumed that setcounter enumi would neutralise the resume: clearly it doesn't!

Comment: @Geoff: you can create a new list environment which incorporates the key `start=1`.